# why EMPTY is not shown when transaction is empty and why is there different output for different users when code is the same(on same page)

Tags: php

I am new to php, I hope you guys can understand what I'm trying to say here.

I don't understand why that the same code is used, but the output for different users is totally different.

My code goes like this, if my transaction is NOT EMPTY, it will echo out the items, ELSE it will echo out "empty".
This code works well for my this user (john)
however, when another user (david) uses it, the output is different.
there will be multiple "empty" being echo out.

I wonder why is this so?
because for john,  "empty" only echo out once.
however for david, "empty" echo out multiple times.
BUT coding are on the same page.

I have another question too.
Right now after I've change my code to the following as shown below,
when my cart is empty, the "empty" is not shown.
Why is it so?

this is my coding

```
<?php
do{

$des = $row_supermarketcart['productdes'];
$pack = $row_supermarketcart['package'];
$price = $row_supermarketcart['itemprice'];
$qty = $row_supermarketcart['qty'];
$ddate  = $row_supermarketcart['ddate']   ;

if ($row_supermarketcart['username'] == $_SESSION['MM_Username'] )
{

            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>". $des ."</td>";
            echo "<td>". $pack. "</td>";
            echo "<td>$" .$price. "</td>";
            echo "<td>". $qty. "</td>";
            echo "<td>".$ddate."</td>";



}

else
{
     echo "<br>";
      echo "<center><b>YOU HAVE NOT MAKE ANY TRANSACTION YET</b></center>";
      echo "<br>";
      echo "<br>";

}

} while ($row_supermarketcart = mysql_fetch_assoc($supermarketcart));
?>
```

my full coding

```
 <?php require_once('Connections/MyDatabase.php'); ?>
<?php
//initialize the session
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}

// ** Logout the current user. **
$logoutAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?doLogout=true";
if ((isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) && ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] != "")){
  $logoutAction .="&". htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if ((isset($_GET['doLogout'])) &&($_GET['doLogout']=="true")){
  //to fully log out a visitor we need to clear the session varialbles
  $_SESSION['MM_Username'] = NULL;
  $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] = NULL;
  $_SESSION['PrevUrl'] = NULL;
  unset($_SESSION['MM_Username']);
  unset($_SESSION['MM_UserGroup']);
  unset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']);

  $logoutGoTo = "login.php";
  if ($logoutGoTo) {
    header("Location: $logoutGoTo");
    exit;
  }
}
?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}



mysql_select_db($database_MyDatabase, $MyDatabase);
//$sql_username = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['MM_Username']);
$query_supermarketcart = "SELECT * FROM supermarketcart ORDER BY `ddate` DESC";
//$query_supermarketcart = "SELECT * FROM supermarketcart ORDER BY `ddate` DESC;";
$supermarketcart = mysql_query($query_supermarketcart, $MyDatabase) or die(mysql_error());
$row_supermarketcart = mysql_fetch_assoc($supermarketcart);
$totalRows_supermarketcart = mysql_num_rows($supermarketcart);
$query_cart = "SELECT * FROM user_data";
$cart = mysql_query($query_cart, $MyDatabase) or die(mysql_error());
$row_cart = mysql_fetch_assoc($cart);
$totalRows_cart = mysql_num_rows($cart);
?>


<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Your Past Transaction</title>
</head>

<body background="background.jpg">
<table width="1024" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#EBF4FA">
  <tr>
    <td><img src="logo.png" width="450" height="86" hspace="50"> 
    </td>
    <td>
      <blockquote><h4><?php echo "Welcome,".($_SESSION['MM_Username']) ?></h4> </blockquote>
  <blockquote><img src="cart.png" alt="cart" width="35" border="0" usemap="#Map">
    <a href="feedback.php">Feedback</a>
     <a href="<?php echo $logoutAction ?>">Logout</a>

    </blockquote></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
<table width="1024" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#EBF4FA">
 <tr>
 <td><img src="back.png" alt="back"  height="30" border="0" usemap="#Map">
 <img src="cart-navigation.png"  height="20" border="0" usemap="#Map2" > 
 <h2>Past Transaction</h2>   
 <hr></td>
 </tr>

</table>
<table width="1024" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#EBF4FA">
 <tr>
 <td>

<table width="800" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#EBF4FA">
<tr>
<td>Item</td>
<td>Package</td>
<td>Price</td>
<td>Quantity</td>
<td>Date of Purchase</td>

</tr>
<?php
if (mysql_num_rows($supermarketcart) > 0)
{
do{

$des = $row_supermarketcart['productdes'];
$pack = $row_supermarketcart['package'];
$price = $row_supermarketcart['itemprice'];
$qty = $row_supermarketcart['qty'];
$ddate  = $row_supermarketcart['ddate']   ;


if ($row_supermarketcart['username'] == $_SESSION['MM_Username'] )
{

            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>". $des ."</td>";
            echo "<td>". $pack. "</td>";
            echo "<td>$" .$price. "</td>";
            echo "<td>". $qty. "</td>";
            echo "<td>".$ddate."</td>";



}
} while ($row_supermarketcart = mysql_fetch_assoc($supermarketcart));
}

else
{
     echo "<br>";
      echo "<center><b>YOU HAVE NOT MAKE ANY TRANSACTION YET</b></center>";
      echo "<br>";
      echo "<br>";

}


?>

<!--<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>-->

</tr>
</table>

</td>
</tr>
</td>

</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It looks like you're selecting all rows, you need to limit that to the correct user.

Comment: what u mean, and how can I do so

Comment: You should post your database retrieval codes, the sql, etc..

Comment: I've just edited my code

Answer (score 0):

Your sql looks like:

```
$query_supermarketcart = "SELECT * FROM supermarketcart ORDER BY `ddate` DESC;";
```

So you are getting all rows from your database where you only need the rows for the logged in user.

What you should do in the sql is something like:

```
$sql_username = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['MM_Username']);
$query_supermarketcart = "SELECT * FROM supermarketcart WHERE username={$sql_username} ORDER BY `ddate` DESC";
```

Now you only have the rows of the logged in user in your result set so you can do:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($supermarketcart) > 0)
{
  do {

    // your whole cart echo code

  } while ($row_supermarketcart = mysql_fetch_assoc($supermarketcart));
}
else
{
     echo "<br>";
     echo "<center><b>YOU HAVE NOT MAKE ANY TRANSACTION YET</b></center>";
     echo "<br>";
     echo "<br>";
}
```

Please note that the `mysql_*` functions and you should switch to PDO or mysqli using prepared statements.

Comment: Unknown column 'test' in 'where clause'

this error was shown

Comment: I've change my code as shown above.
the output seems to be same now.
However, 
when the transaction is empty,
"empty" is not shown